# How to make the iframe scrollable to show all content?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to finish off our rehoming page, where a visitor clicks on an animal to open an iframe with more info output from our database. But I can't get the iframe scrollable. I've searched online extensively but can't get any of the suggestions to work.

What am I doing wrong? (I'm way out of my league with code but just doing the best I can with what I find online, so I may have made some basic errors.) Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<title>iFrame</title>
<script>
asm3_adoptable_filters = "size agegroup sex breed species";
asm3_adoptable_extra = function(a) {
    return '<span class="waitingtime">Time waiting for a home: ' + a.TIMEONSHELTER + '</span>';
}
asm3_adoptable_iframe = true;
asm3_adoptable_iframe_fixed = true;
asm3_adoptable_translations = {
    "(any sex)": "Any sex",
    "(any size)": "Any size",
    "(any breed)": "Any breed",
    "(any age)": "Any age",
    "(any species)": "Any species"
}
asm3_adoptable_sort = "-@DAYSONSHELTER";
</script>
<style>
.waitingtime {
    color: black;
    font-family: filson soft regular,sans-serif;
</style>
<div id="asm3-adoptables"></div>
<script src="https://service.sheltermanager.com/asmservice?method=animal_view_adoptable_js&account=sm1510"
></script>
```

Page CSS:

```
#asm3-adoptable-iframe-overlay{
    background-color: rgba(0 0 0 / 57%) !important;
}
#asm3-adoptable-iframe{
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    width: 479px !important;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    height: 90vh !important;
    background-color:white;
    margin-top:3em;
}
#asm3-adoptable-iframe-close{
    background-color: #c92327;
    color: white;
    padding: 7px 23px;
    /* margin-top: 39px !important; */
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 34px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top:44px;
}
```

Element CSS:

```
.asm3-adoptable-item {
            display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    width: 31.8%;
    margin: 10px;
}
.asm3-adoptable-item:hover {
     background-color: black;
}
.asm3-adoptable-item:hover .asm3-adoptable-tagline {
    color: white;
}
.asm3-adoptable-name {
    font-family: "proxima soft extrabold", sans-serif;
    font-size: 44px;
    color: #c92327;
    margin-top: -16px;
    display: block; 
}
.asm3-adoptable-tagline {
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-family: "proxima soft extrabold",sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    margin-top: -10px;
    display: block;
}
.asm3-adoptable-item:hover .asm3-adoptable-name {
    color: #c92327;
}
.asm3-adoptable-item:hover .waitingtime {
    color: white;
}
.asm3-adoptable-thumbnail {
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 425px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 425px;
}
.asm3-adoptable-reserved {
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: "proxima soft extrabold", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18pt;
}
.asm3-adoptable-reserved span:before {
    content: "RESERVED";
}
.asm3-adoptable-reserved span {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    right: -60px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50px;
    background: #c92327;
    width: 275px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#asm3-adoptable-filters {
    overflow:hidden;
}
#asm3-adoptable-filters select {
    width: 17%;
    float: left;
    margin: 20px;
}
#asm3-adoptable-filters { 
    font-family: "proxima soft extrabold", sans-serif; 
    font-size: 22px;
    background-color: #dab348; 
}
.asm3-adoptable-list {
        display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .asm3-adoptable-item {
   width:50%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .asm3-adoptable-item {
      width:100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing bracket "}" in your <style> tags. After playing around with your website a little I believe you are talking about some sort of full screen modal. But then it seems you are using a iframe in the modal. You might consider not using an iframe because there is really no need and it may solve your problems. Another thing I noticed is that you don't have any links between your html and your css which you might want to look into.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking a look, Steven. But this website is currently locked and can't be accessed without a password. Maybe you were looking at our current site? Strangely, that site has a scrollable iframe and, when I just copy the code exactly and put it on the new site, it won't scroll. If I use full screen, it still doesn't scroll. I prefer not to use full screen, as that would take the site visitor to a page from our database company, and I want to keep them on our website.

Comment: It's really frustrating, because it scrolls on the old site but not the new. You're welcome to check out the new site: https://AnimalCareTrust.org.uk/rehome (pass code: 9903).

Thanks again, Steven. I really appreciate your help. (And I fixed the missing closed curly bracket).